# Iterate along list while mutating it

Tags: loops, iterator

This example concerns a list `lst` of numbers `[1,2,5,6,3,8,9,10]` which I want to iterate while modifying with a for-loop. Suppose the intended modification occurs for sum, i.e., we add the current number `x` to the respective element `y` of the complementary list if it fulfills a specific condition i.e. `y <= 5`.

I am not looking for an implementation code but the python behavior.

The iteration steps I expect are:

Initial: `[1,2,5,6,3,8,9,10]`

1. `[3,5,6,3,8,9,10]`
2. `[8,6,3,8,9,10]`
3. `[11,6,8,9,10]`

Will the next element follow which rule?

In a more generic example: given a list `[a,b,c,d,e]`, do we go along elements `a`, `b`, pop `c` on `b`, than `d` and `e`?

Comment: "I am not looking for an implementation code but the python behavior." - it's not clear what you mean by that. What are you looking for the behavior *of*, more specifically than just "python"?

Comment: With your edit... that's not something that makes sense to ask *us*. The behavior you need is part of your problem requirements, not something that we or Python can decide for you.